# Error when calling method from mounted Property 'function' does not exist on type

Tags: vue.js, ionic3

I get this error "Property 'load' does not exist on type '{ name: string; components: { IonHeader:"
When I'm trying to call the function load from mounted().
Message shows in console  but I get this error.

```
<script lang="ts">
import {
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent,
  //IonIcon,
  //IonButtons,
  IonButton,
  alertController,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { logOut, add } from "ionicons/icons";
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import "../style/Home.scss";
export default {
  name: "ListDatos",
  components: {
    IonHeader,
    IonToolbar,
    IonTitle,
    IonContent,
    IonButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "",
      datos: [],
    };
  },
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    return {
      add,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Test mounted");
    this.load();
  },
  methods: {

    load(){
      console.log("function load()");
    },
    
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because TypeScript is trying to guess the type and since you are doing: `export default {...all your code...}` for TS that is just an object, you need to indicate that it is not just an object and in fact it is a Vue component, here is the code extracted from the docs (check the [docs here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html))

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const Component = Vue.extend({
  // type inference enabled
})
```

As you can see on that code, the component definition is wrapped in `Vue.extend()` so you could have your code:

```
export default Vue.extend({
   //...your component...
})
```